# Increase the complexity of RNNs

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have been working on a big data set on which I have been trying different machine learning algorithms. I have been getting really good results with XGBoost but the best results I got were from SVM. But as I had data spread across 8 years and it's a time series model hence I thought of using RNNs as well. I have been experimenting with the hyper parameters of RNN-LSTMs by increasing the number of layers or the number of nodes per layer as there is no rule of thumb as such. But still I am not even getting closer to my XGBoost results. And the weird thing I am noticing is that even if I increase the number of epochs from 100 to 1000 or I increase the number of hidden layers from 1 to 3 or I change the nodes per layer, the performance of the model is always the same both for training and test sets. I am sharing my RNN-LSTMs code and please let me know if I am missing anything. Theoretically it would at least be as good as SVM if not better as the data quality is also really good and lengthy.

```
# Getting the inputs and the ouputs
X = allData.iloc[:-48,:-1].values
y = allData.iloc[:-48,-1].values
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc_x = MinMaxScaler()
sc_y = MinMaxScaler()
X = sc_x.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
y = np.ravel(y)
X = np.reshape(X, (-1,1,X.shape[1]))
y = np.reshape(y, (-1,1,1))

# Building RNN
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 8,activation = 'tanh',recurrent_activation = 'relu',return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X.shape[1],X.shape[2])))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 3,activation = 'tanh', recurrent_activation ='relu', return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units = 1)))
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X, y, batch_size = 32,shuffle = False, epochs = 100,validation_split=0.1)
```

I am not able to get even comparable accuracy from this model. What other things can I try in RNNs to make to perform at least similar to other machine learning algorithms?

Comment: What is the final shape of X and y before it gets sent into the RNN? Also why are you not using the default activations in LSTMs? I never touch those options. Shuffle should always be true unless you are using stateful LSTMs.

Comment: The final shape of X is (3163,24,5) and of y is (3163,24,1). 24 is because the data is hourly data so I thought 24 will provide the best possible information for the LSTMs. I tried using default activations as well but same results. I put shuffle as false because I was not sure how the the time series will be maintained if one batch of 2016 is linked with one batch 2013 (if I am getting the right sense of shuffle). I tried using stateful LSTMs but they performed even worse.

Comment: Just some tips. 1. Use Standard Scaler 2. Do you use the same scalar for XgBoost? 3. Use default activations 4. Increase your batch size, say 256 5. Increase units to say 32 atleast on both. 6. You need to prepare your data in a special order to feed into stateful LSTM (ignore stateful for now). 7. Post results for XgBoost vs LSTM MSE above.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip. 1) 3) 4) 5) Will try this. 2) For SVM and XGBoost, no scaler was used. 6. What exactly do you mean by that? How can I prepare in special order? I have done less bit of feature engineering for RNNs in comparison to SVM and XGBoost for example haven't taken any lags as RNNs are assumed to incorporate those information. 7. MSE for SVM- 243, XGBoost- 270, RNN- 350.

Comment: I tried making those changes but the MSE came around 450. @Sachin_ruk

Comment: I got a feeling that there are bigger problems with your model. If you have scaled your data to be between 0 and 1 and your MSE>>1 for any ML model, whether its DL or XgBoost to me is saying that you havent scaled your data. Also it's common courtesy to upvote good comments/ answers.

Comment: The final MSE I am mentioning here is calculated by un-scaling the data. And in other models I didn't scale my data. There is no point in calculating the MSE with scaled data (for RNN) as then I cannot compare it with other models.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting trying a simple multi-level perceptron model before you tweak it to include RNN layers. I faced a similar situation and in the end, I used the XGBoost model, not because the accuracy was comparable, but it was far easier to explain and understand.

Also, try to convert your problem to a classification one (bin Y into classes etc.).

Comment: Totally agreed with the transparency factor of XGBoost and yes I will be trying a simple multi-level perceptron model too, just to set the benchmark for the neural network model. But what if for now the end result (accuracy) is the only thing I care about, even if it is coming from a black box, as long as it is robust which can be seen from its performance on a validation and a test set? 
Also converting it into a classification problem can be useful sometimes but I have a requirement to get the exact number rather than a range so can not do it in this case but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using stateful LSTMs in order to get the full benefits of long-term dependencies. I would also recommend not using min-max scaling and perhaps trying mean-std scaling and then clipping values between -1,1 or 0,1. Also, it seems weird to me having relu in the recurrent connection. Perhaps try using a symmetric one.

Comment: Yes will be trying stateful LSTMs. I was confused when to use reset_state() parameter while running it as if I set batch size as 1 and then use reset_state() after each epoch the it will remember the whole series which means the whole 5 6 years. I want it to remember seasonal patterns more than annual so hoping I can reset_state accordingly. 
And does this type of scaling mean 2 layers of scaling. First we do standardisation and over that we use min max and make everything in a range of (-1,1) or (0,1)? 
Will try using tanh or sigmoid then for recurrent connection.

Comment: I actually think it is better to use some fixed scaler and clip the data. Sometimes with min max you can lose a lot of variance if there is an outlier which gets attributed to the min or max. 

You are right calling reset_state() after batch size 1 will mean it wont reset each year but only after the entire 5-6 years. If you want to reset after each year just split into 5-6 annual examples and reset state between each one again with batch size 1.

Comment: Won't clipping of data affect the time-series nature of data? So I tried a stateful LSTMs and instead of taking whole 5 6 years, I just took 1 year and then let the model learn everything. When I used activation as relu, I was getting training loss as nan so I changed it to sigmoid and the mse is close to 400 now. I think there is a bit of overfitting going on now. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: No i meant clipping as in normalising within a range smaller than min max. So you will have values such as 1.2 or -0.2 but you can just reassign those to 1 or 0. Good luck with the rest of your modelling.